# Destructure a bunch of variables from an object

Tags: destructuring, object-destructuring

I have an object in Javascript as follows:

```
profile= {
                profilePicture: null,
                username: null,
                age: null,
                gender: null,
                followedBy: [],
                following: [],
                aboutMe: null
            }
```

And I would like to destructure all of the properties into variables, like such:

```
const {userName, age, gender, followedBy, following, aboutMe} = profile
```

Let's say in the future this profile object will have 30 properties, how can I iterate over all the properties instead of typing them one by one? I was thinking something like this

```
const {userName, age, ...rest} = profile
```

but instead of the rest variable, it actually gives me all the other property names as stand-alone variable names that I can use. I tried something like

```
const {...Object.keys(profile)} = profile
```

but it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: What language are you working in? Please [edit] to add the relevant language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the curly bracket to square bracket

**For Example**

```
const [userName, age, gender, followedBy, following, aboutMe] = profile

const [userName, age, ...rest] = profile
```